# Target Unreachable, identifier 'xxxBean' resolved to null when running JasperReports 6.0.1

Tags: jsf-2, jasper-reports

I have an application that was working fine until I added code to run a JasperReport. The error is the well known

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'studentBean' resolved to null
```

After adding the code needed to run a JasperReport, the particular page that uses that bean (`StudenBean`) started to show such an exception before it even shows. After a process of commenting/uncommenting lines of code, I could isolate de precise line that brings the problem. It's shown below:

```
private void gerarRelatorioPDF(List<Student> students, InputStream report, OutputStream pdf) {
    JRDataSource jrds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(students);
    try {
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(report, pdf, null, jrds); // <<-- Here!!!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's the line that generates a PDF stream from a JasperReport definition. This method is `private` because it's called by another `public` method. The `public` method is the action of a `<p:commandButton/>` in the page, so this button is not even being clicked, because the exception prevents the page to render.

If I comment that line of code, the page renders ok and I can click the button, but obviously no report will be generated.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some study, I decided to modify my `POM.xml` (Maven script) to include [JasperReports 6.0.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.0.0). Previously I had only installed JasperReports 6.0.1 plugin in Eclipse, created and configured the report.

When we add a new report to a project, Eclipse automatically adds the path to JasperReports libraries to the class path, so the project compiles fine, but it seems that some other dependencies are not added and, specially, not deployed to the application server (in my case JBoss AS 7.1).

After updating the POM.xml to include JasperReports, everything started to work as desired.